# Possible to do a conditional 301 in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, conditional-statements

I'm actually not sure where to start with this one.

Basically I have a buddy in SEO and one of his clients sites has been duplicated by a certain web hosting service and the duplicate has not been removed in spite of turning it off. The preview site in question has a higher PR than the actual client site so SEO is being completely destroyed as a result.

The only control we have managed to get over the situation is the fact that the files (but not the .htaccess) are propagating from the client's server. Basically, it's a freaking nightmare.

What I am proposing to do is set up a conditional redirect in the PHP header files so that if the browser/engine hits the preview site, it will 301 to the client site. If, however, the browser/engine is hitting the correct site, we need to do nothing.

While I could probably figure out the syntax by trial & error, this is sort of time sensitive since the client in question has an SEO campaign that is going straight to Hades.

I'm hoping someone here will know how to format the conditional redirect.

Let's call the two domains:

previewdomain.com
domain.com

So loosely speaking...

```
if current url == previewdomain.com then 301 redirect to domain.com
else do nothing
```

Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You should try writing it. It involves `if()` and a `$_SERVER` variable or two. Try `print_r($_SERVER)` to figure out which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll do:

```
if( stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"previewdomain.com") !== false) {
    header("Location: http://domain.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],true,301);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` though, `PHP_SELF` might be different due to rewrites.

Comment: They're functionally identical, except mine handles the case where the domain name isn't all lowercase (like `PREVIEWDOMAIN.COM`), and his uses a `301` like you requested whereas mine uses `302` - that said I'm not sure if that's true since Andrew's seems like it'll try to send 301 but get overwritten by a 302. Oh, also mine dies to end the current script if the redirect is happening.

Comment: Ow, and don't forget the `301` to make the redirect _permanent_ to recover some link juice.

Comment: @Imperative: Kolink forgets the 301, Andrew just redirects to base domain instead of every page to it's new location, combine the 2 to 1 which does both ;)

Comment: Yeah 302 doesn't actually solve the problem. Is there anything I can do to assure it's a 301? 302 redirects but doesn't tell Google to update its index.

Comment: After the URL, before the closing `)`, add these two arguments: `true, 301`. This will cause the redirect to happen with a `301` status code.

Comment: Well, as said: take the 301 from Kolink, take the per-page redirect (so `previewdomain.com/foobar => domain.com/foobar` instead of `=> domain.com/`) from this one.

Comment: if you read the exact pseudo code he asks for a domain check, and redirect to a domain, no added URI ;)

Comment: For the sake of the future, could you post the full version to its own answer so I can mark it correct? Future readers may not bother reading this far.

Or, rather, just edit this answer.

Comment: Edited. I have also adjusted it to use the suggestion @Wrikken gave.

Comment: Thanks Kolink! Some days I think stackoverflow is my favorite site on the entire Internet.

Comment: I think SO is my favourite site every day :p

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'previewdomain.com') !== FALSE) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com"); 
}
```

Comment: mine is correct as it also outputs the 301 redirect header, the other answer does not :)

Comment: Note you can skip one header call by calling just `header("Location: http://www.domain.com", true, 301);`

Comment: yes you can :D but best to keep it obvious when someone is trying to learn ;)

Comment: @Andrew: but Kolinks redirect does every page to it's proper new location, which is also interesting to recover some link juice ;) But yes, 301 it should be.

Comment: yes it does but that wasn't part of the question was it :p and it also erroneously outputs a ? at the end of the URL if there's no query string ;)